# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded and [Violation] 'click' handler took

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I checked other post like this but honestly I don't find a solution. I have a button "test", and when I hit the button theoretically I gotta open up a new window showing a query result but, I'm getting this error and honestly I'm not understanding why!
In item_action.php I wrote this code just for test:

```html
if ($_POST['btn_action'] == 'item_view') { //View Item details
    echo "test";
}
```

Below the code in the javascript file

```js
//OPEN DETAIL ITEM WINDOW IN MODE VIEW 
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    //var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
    //Declare 2 vars 
    var item_id = 3;
    var btn_action = 'item_view';
    $('#productModalView').modal('show');
    $.ajax({
        url: "item_action.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            product_id: product_id,
            btn_action: btn_action
        },
        success: function(critto) {
            $('#itemview').html(critto);
        },
        error: function() {
            $('<div>').html('Found an error!');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="productModalView" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form method="post" id="product_form_view">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Item Product</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- Close Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="itemview"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Close Modal Body-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="btn_action" id="btn_action" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
                <!-- Close Modal Footer -->
            </div>
            <!-- Close Modal Content -->
        </form>
        <!-- Close Form -->
    </div>
    <!-- Close Modal-Dialog -->
</div>
<!-- Close Product Modal -->
```

Any idea how to fix it???

Comment: What is the error msg?

Comment: Where is the element with `id` test? Think it is an infinite loop issue (Not 100% sure)

Comment: Yes this is an infinite loop but I'd like to understand why... What's wrong with that code?